# How to find a repeated letter in a string with Regular Expressions - Python3

Tags: python, regex, string, python-re

I've tried a lot of differents ways, but I can't make this work. I need to capture two differents strings with regular expressions (I'm using RE on Py3).

1. **I need to take a substring with the same letter repetead 3 times**.
2. I need to take a substring that is XYX, like "BAB" or "ACA" (I don't even know how to start on this)

````
opções = "abc aab aaa acb acvd ccd bb bbb dsa dssd ssss" #the string 

regular = re.compile('([a-z])\3') #I need to find "aaa", "bbb" and etc., but not "sss" or "bb"

print(regular)
print(re.findall(regular, opções))```
````

Comment: You're looking for `\b([a-z])\1\1\b`

Comment: I tried, but no success. It returns "[]" as output :/

Comment: Does `' aaab '` or `' abbb '` match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problems

You have a few problems:

1. Your regex `([a-z])\3` captures a single lowercase alpha character, then tries to match capture group 3 (which doesn't exist)
2. You use `re.findall(regular, string)` but you've already compiled the regex into `regular`, so you should be calling it as `regular.findall(string)`
3. You encased your regex in single quotes (good) `'` but your regex contains a backslash. To escape it you need to use `r''`

---

### Solution

Fixing all of the above, we get the following.

#### `finditer` method

[See code working here](https://tio.run/##DYuxDsMgDER3vsLKEhgatercLyEMNhDVUgPIoEjtz1Pfu6ebrn3Hu5bnnHy2KgMkG9PhBQtSBERSETDqxitBjAmItASpo9oTdM1iRD@St1jPxp9sZd3Jerz9gtsfCq3OmCZchvXs7wGOKsDABWQ7uCQeWWx3wc35Bw)

```
import re

s = "abc aab aaa acb acvd ccd bb bbb dsa dssd ssss"
r = re.compile(r'\b([a-z])\1\1\b')

print([i[0] for i in r.finditer(s)])
```

The regex works by ensuring word boundaries around the words `\b` so that we match exactly 3 repetitions and no more (as your question specifies - match `bbb` but not `sss` in `ssss`).

The list comprehension loops over the results of `finditer` to only give us the first element in each match (otherwise we would get a list that looks like this for each element `('aaa', 'a')`).

#### `findall` method

[See code working here](https://tio.run/##DYsxCsMwEAR7vWJxY6mICU6dl1gu7iSbHNiSOBlD8nlFww5bTflen5xerclZsl7QzZiKNwbiACLuEij0D3dECBHMfYxYqVsjamcw2hvdppDPIsdmdfRs7UKP3@r87GfneXTGFJV02UWW54o9KwSSoNMuKdJx2OpW19of)

```
import re

s = "abc aab aaa acb acvd ccd bb bbb dsa dssd ssss"
r = re.compile(r'\b(([a-z])\2\2)\b')

print([i[0] for i in r.findall(s)])
```

Comment: Wow, worked really great! Thanks :) 
But, using the same logic I can't go with the next part. I tried:
`r'\b([a-z])(?!\1)\1\b` 

PS: I put a "aba" inside of the string for the tests hahahaha
PSS: I also tried some differents options as `\b(\w)\1(?!\1)\1\b`

Comment: @ViniciusRochaPerrud the negative lookahead doesn’t consume characters, so you have a contradicting regex pattern at `(?!\1)\1` (next char can’t be what we just captured; move to next char -> it must be what we captured). That’s like saying `if x!=1 && x==1` (it’s always `false`). You probably want `\b(\w)(?!\1)\w\1\b`

Comment: I don't know what you are. But for me, it's an angel!